# How to start a linux binary on FreeBSD, from within a ruby exec()?

Tags: ruby, emulation, freebsd

On FreeBSD 13 AMD64 I have some Linux binaries (wkhtmltopdf in this case), who are running fine from a standard shell. But who fails to run from within a Ruby exec() statement.

1. I am using Linux binaries because the FreeBSD builds are broken.
2. It is my understanding that FreeBSD is normally detecting the ELF file type and redirects all necessary files (like linked libaries) to /compat/linux/...
3. This seems not to happening when run from within an exec() statement.
4. The execution fails with:
   `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: error while loading shared libraries: /usr/local/lib/libpng16.so.16: ELF file OS ABI invalid`

I unsuccessfully tried to start the command from `/compat/linux/bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'`

How could I proceed to make Ruby execute this binary in Linux emulation mode?

Comment: What tells `$ file /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf` plz ? ... expecting `version 1 (SYSV)` somewhere instead of `version 1 (FreeBSD)`.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=e63267ee15e16422bdc4c70a6c5593dd967000c0, stripped

Comment: You have to install `graphics/linux-c7-png` (or from whatever distro you are using) which provides `usr/lib/libpngXX.so.XX` ;  `$ ldd /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf` will tell you what's is missing or error prone.

Comment: I already installed all the libraries in /compat/linux/usr/lib64, and it works fine from commandline... but not from the Ruby exec() statement.

Comment: it seems when calling `Ruby's exec` from a FreeBSD ELF binary, you load the right interpreter (Linux ABI), but you didn't use the right shared library, so instead of using the Linux hints file for the dynamic linker (`ld-elf.so.hints`), you are using the FreeBSD one (from `/var/run`). You have to specify the right environment to Ruby eg modifying some `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Be sure Ruby doesn't override itself some environment. If it works from your `shell`, it has to work with `Ruby` as well. No magic.

Comment: So, remove your own answer, and would you plz let me put this as an answer, so I could get some points in order to improve my SO reputation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you remove your comment when you told to me my advises lead to  solve your issue ?! Do you really want to justify your own answer from my information as you did it alone ?!! Gosh, so childish.

Comment: I'm sorry Valery, I was not fully aware that this was not good practice. I removed my answer. I did not, however, remove any of my comments. Please excuse this misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: that's ok, you got a solution, that was what matters. So, I publish the answer for other users.

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf` was started, so calling `Ruby's exec()` was done through the Linux ABI, because using an `exec()` call from Ruby is later done through a `syscall` to the OS. You simply failed at fetching the right shared library.

FreeBSD has a list of loaders, instead of a single loader.
From the FreeBSD perspective, it sees the magic number as an ELF binary. The ELF loader looks for a specialized brand, which is a comment section in the ELF image, and which is not present on SVR4 ELF binaries. This is done using `brandelf` utility.

From the documentation, we know:

> FreeBSD's Linux mode dynamically reroots lookups. This is, in effect,
> equivalent to union file system mounts. First, an attempt is made to
> look up the file in `/compat/linux/original-path`. If that fails, the
> lookup is done in `/original-path`

So, in your case, you have to check if the Ruby's environment doesn't override this mechanism, like `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, from what you told me in afterwards,
by adding `ENV['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] = '/compat/linux/usr/lib64'` before the `exec()`

I strongly recommend to see the FreeBSD's documentation that really worth a read : [Chapter 11. Linux Binary Compatibility](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/linuxemu/) and more specifically [11.5.5](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/linuxemu/#linuxemu-misc) which describes the whole process.

Finally, FreeeBSD's Linux compatibility is really powerful, once you understand how it works, I'm able to play with the `Linux's XPlane-11` simulator, and use some sophisticated software like eg `VisualParadigm`, without any bugs.